# Conditionally wrapping React component without losing children state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I was wondering if it's possible to conditionally wrap a React component without losing the state of the children.

In the sandbox, you can see when clicking the Increment button a few times, followed by the "Wrap children" or "Unwrap children" action, the counter is reset.

https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-herschel-f62e2?file=/src/App.js

The relevant code can be seen here:

```
const ConditionalWrap = ({ condition, children }) => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {condition ? (
        <div>{children}</div>
      ) : (
        children
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

1. Can anyone point me to a resource why this is happening? I guess the parent tree needs to stay the same, I'd just like to know why.
2. Is there some way to keep the state of all the `children` when conditionally wrapping them in an element or context provider?

Comment: I'd think the sub-tree would be re-mounted when wrapped in the new DOM element. I don't think there's any re-parenting support in React yet--I think the canonical solution is to move the state up (or use different state mechanism). See, e.g., https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3965. Portals might work--I don't know enough about them.

Comment: There's also https://github.com/Paol-imi/react-reparenting

Answer (score 3):

There's explanations of the reconciliation in the [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#elements-of-different-types).

React sees two elements of different types and so tears down the old and puts in a new.

There isn't a way to keep the state of all the children. It might be a good idea to either keep them wrapped in the same element. Or move the state into context, redux, or props that you pass down.

There is a library someone built for the purpose of reparenting: https://github.com/httptoolkit/react-reverse-portal